# Can we distribute different version of single app to different client through app store or any other way?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-distribution

We have one iOS app and we have single code base and all just need to create separate build for different clients. We need to distribute the app to all of them how can we distribute thought enterprise or vpp or any other way?

Thanks,

Comment: I have also faced same problem. is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

YES, you can achieve this by using **apple beta testing with test Flight** which is integrated in **iTunesConnect**. This new integration has made the things easy for the beta testing. You have to upload your build to iTunes and add beta tester there and distribute it to them.
Here is the tutorial which tells you every step in details.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial

Hope this will help you.